# iTunes Connect Transporter - Lookup - GameCenter Leaderboard Set not part of metadata

Tags: xcode, app-store, metadata, app-store-connect, itmstransporter

I just used iTMSTransporter for the first time. I did a lookup and downloaded my app's metadate as a .itmsp file.

My app / game contains leaderboards with leaderboard sets, but in the metadata.xml file (in the .itmsp file/folder) only the leaderboards themselves are defined. The leaderboard sets are not defined.

Ultimately, I want to be able to define all my leaderboards and leaderboard sets in an XML file and upload them to iTunesConnect with Transporter.

Why are the leaderboard sets not part of the metadata file?
What can I do to manage my leaderboards and leaderboard sets with an XML file and upload them to iTunes Connect with transporter?

Comment: Have you found a way to do it? I'm utterly surprised on how poor some of Apple's documentation is. Specially around metadata and transporter.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's Transporter doesn't yet support LeaderboardSets.

https://help.apple.com/itc/transporteruserguide/en.lproj/static.html

This is a pretty poor effort on Apple's behalf.

Thousands of developers having to manually handle their localized text is wildy inefficient and error prone.